# How to get different aggregations for different params in bool in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Document structure:

```
{
  "_index" : "admin",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "9rEy94EB7k-V-3UYmchn",
  "_source" : {
    "entity_title" : "Title CPP",
    "entity_type" : "type1",
    "entity_score" : 185346,
    "entity" : {
      "customer_id" : "cid1",
      "customer_name" : "cname1",
    }
  }
}

{
  "_index" : "admin",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "9rEy94EB7k-V-3UYmchn",
  "_source" : {
    "entity_title" : "Title APP",
    "entity_type" : "type1",
    "entity_score" : 12,
    "entity" : {
      "customer_id" : "cid2",
      "customer_name" : "cname2",
    }
  }
}
```

My query

```
GET /admin/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : { 
      "should" : [
        {
          "query_string" : {"default_field" : "entity_title", "query" : "app*"}
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {"entity_title": {"value": "app"}}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
"aggs": {
  "by_entity_type": {
    "terms":{
        "field":"entity_type",
        "size": 4 <total number of entity types>
    },
    "aggs": {
      "by_top_score":{"top_hits":{"size":10, "sort": {"entity_score": {"order" : "desc", "mode" : "avg"}}}}
    }
  }
}
```

I need to

1. Aggregate all search results by entity_type.
2. Sort the results of matched query (query_string) by _score.
3. Sort results of fuzzy search by 'entity_score'.

Kindly help me to fetch this as a separate or in same aggregation.
Thanks.

Comment: did you try `collapse` with `inner_hits` ? you may achive with collapse.

Comment: @SagarPatel I'm unable to write inner_hits in should query.

Comment: @SagarPatel How can I add a document field to _score field? Something like this:
"query" : {
    "bool" : { 
      "should" : [
        {
          "query_string" : {"default_field" : "entity_title", "query" : "app*", "boost": "_score + doc.entity_score"}
        },
        {
          "fuzzy": {"entity_title": {"value": "app"}}
        }
      ]
    }
  }